# Blockwise sum of matrix elements

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, vectorization

I want to go from something like this:

```
1> a = matrix(c(1,4,2,5,2,5,2,1,4,4,3,2,1,6,7,4),4)
1> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    4    1
[2,]    4    5    4    6
[3,]    2    2    3    7
[4,]    5    1    2    4
```

To something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12   15
[2,]   10   16
```

...without using for-loops, plyr, or otherwise without looping.  Possible?  I'm trying to shrink a geographic lat/long dataset from 5 arc-minutes to half-degree, and I've got an ascii grid.  A little function where I specify blocksize would be great.  I've got hundreds of such files, so things that allow me to do it quickly without parallelization/supercomputers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication for this.

```
# Computation matrix:

mat <- function(n, r) {
  suppressWarnings(matrix(c(rep(1, r), rep(0, n)), n, n/r))
}
```

Square-matrix example, uses a matrix and its transpose on each side of `a`:

```
# Reduce a 4x4 matrix by a factor of 2:

x <- mat(4, 2)
x
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    0
## [2,]    1    0
## [3,]    0    1
## [4,]    0    1

t(x) %*% a %*% x
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   12   15
## [2,]   10   16
```

Non-square example:

```
b <- matrix(1:24, 4 ,6)
t(mat(4, 2)) %*% b %*% mat(6, 2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   14   46   78
## [2,]   22   54   86
```

Comment: exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks!  my matrix isn't square, but half of it is.

Answer (score 5):

```
tapply(a, list((row(a) + 1L) %/% 2L, (col(a) + 1L) %/% 2L), sum)
#    1  2
# 1 12 15
# 2 10 16
```

I used `1L` and `2L` instead of `1` and `2` so indices remain integers (as opposed to numerics) and it should run faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that might help you, but still it uses sapply which can be considered as loop-ish tool.

```
a <- matrix(c(1,4,2,5,2,5,2,1,4,4,3,2,1,6,7,4),4)
block.step <- 2
res <- sapply(seq(1, nrow(a), by=block.step), function(x) 
    sapply(seq(1, nrow(a), by=block.step), function(y) 
        sum(a[x:(x+block.step-1), y:(y+block.step-1)])
    )
)
res
```

Is it anyhow helpful ?