# Blockwise sum of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

I want to do something similar to this [Blockwise sum of matrix elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884384/blockwise-sum-of-matrix-elements/16885285#16885285), but with an arbitrary given slit pattern. For example, if the rows are split as `row_split = list(block_1=1, block_2=2:3, block_3=4)`, the columns are split as `col_split = list(block_1=1:3, block_2=4)`, then the output is a `2x3` matrix with each element being the blockwise sum.

Any ideas to do that?

Comment: You could do it if you used a different right and left multiplier for the matrix.

Comment: Yes. But unsure how to efficiently create such matrices

Answer (score 0):

A simple vapply statement should do the trick:

```
vapply(row_split,function(x){
    a<-numeric(4)
    a[x]=1
    a
},numeric(4))
```

Result:

```
     block_1 block_2 block_3
[1,]       1       0       0
[2,]       0       1       0
[3,]       0       1       0
[4,]       0       0       1
```

You will need to transpose one of them, but it should do the trick.